# importing google calendar api problem using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, api, plugins, calendar

I imported the google calendar api jars to my current project using the eclipse plugin provided by google.

here is how I did it http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/googleapis.html

and here is what I am trying to do

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

I encounter an error at compilation time. I get no errors or warnings while coding

error

```
Compiling module com.shuttle.reservation.ShuttleWebsite
   Validating newly compiled units
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Dropbox/All/Everything%20Programming/workspace/ShuttleWebsite/src/com/shuttle/reservation/client/ShuttleWebsite.java'
         [ERROR] Line 129: No source code is available for type com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 134: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 135: No source code is available for type com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarFeed; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 142: No source code is available for type com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarEntry; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 146: No source code is available for type com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 149: No source code is available for type java.net.MalformedURLException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 155: No source code is available for type com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.shuttle.reservation.client.ShuttleWebsite'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

some additional error from the console window

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:118)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:100)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:555)
    at AppsProvisioning.main(AppsProvisioning.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

and here is the code and I dont know what to do. I used googles eclipse plugin setup my project I dont know why it is not working. can you help me out

```
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.acl.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.calendar.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

.
.
.
.
//------------  Calendar Service  ---------------------------------------------
         CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0");

         try {
            myService.setUserCredentials("jo@gmail.com", "mypassword");

             URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
             CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);

             textBox.setText("Your calendars");
             //System.out.println("Your calendars:");
             //System.out.println();

             for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
                 CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
                 //System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
                 textBox_1.setText(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
             }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the scope right. GWT cannot import all Java classes into client codes. Things like CalendarService or other Calendar API classes are supposed to be written in server side, not client side.

Please read the tutorial carefully, I think you should be mixing the server and client code together.